# Apache RewriteCond seems to be ignored?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

I have tried various variations of above, but currently the wp-admin rewrite condition is ignored.

I don't want "/wp-admin" directory and "/" root requests redirected! (Yes, I know, sounds funky)

What am I doing wrong in above mod_rewrite?

Comment: /wp-admin is still getting redirected? If you add RewriteLog rules you can see which conditions are being checked and their outcomes.

Comment: Yes, it is. I will try your suggestion and report back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

For anyone in similar situation, you also need

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login
```

(since wp-admin redirects to wp-login)